# How to extract EXIF metadata from BLOB column

Tags: oracle, plsql, exif

I am trying to extract geolocation from EXIF metadata and the JPEG-image is stored in blob column in Oracle Database 12c using PLSQL.

Oracle Multimedia package is installed. The image contains data about geolocation before uploading, and when I download it again from the BLOB, latitude and longitude are there in metadata. But when I try to read it in database, I can read only basic metadata like image width, height, size, mimetype.

I am using this procedure to extract metadata from BLOB column:

```
 PROCEDURE extractMetadata(inID IN INTEGER) IS
  img ORDSYS.ORDIMAGE;
  metav XMLSequenceType;
  meta_root VARCHAR2(40);
  xmlORD XMLType;
  xmlXMP XMLType;
  xmlEXIF XMLType;
  xmlIPTC XMLType;
 
BEGIN
 
-- select the image
SELECT ordsys.ordimage(d.blob,1)
INTO img
FROM PHOTOS d
WHERE d.id = inID;


-- extract all the metadata
metav := img.getMetadata( 'ALL' );
 
-- process the result array to discover what types of metadata were returned
FOR i IN 1..metav.count() LOOP
  meta_root := metav(i).getRootElement();
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(meta_root);
  CASE meta_root
    WHEN 'ordImageAttributes' THEN xmlORD := metav(i);
    WHEN 'xmpMetadata' THEN xmlXMP := metav(i);
    WHEN 'iptcMetadata' THEN xmlIPTC := metav(i);
    WHEN 'exifMetadata' THEN xmlEXIF := metav(i);
    ELSE NULL;
  END CASE;
END LOOP;

-- Update metadata columns
--
update photos SET metaORDImage = xmlORD,
                  metaEXIF = xmlEXIF,
                  metaIPTC = xmlIPTC,
                  metaXMP = xmlXMP
WHERE id = inID;
 
END extractMetadata;
```

but only metaORDImage is extracted.

It seems like there is no EXIF metadata available, but when I download image to my PC and check details, there is location data:

[image]

What could be wrong here? Is it possible at all to extract EXIF from BLOB and should I store the image in some other format rather than BLOB?

UPDATE: I used Javascript library exif-js to read metada on page when the image is loaded into webpage, and once again geolocation is there. I can read it anywhere but not in PLSQL.

```
{
    "ImageWidth": 720,
    "ImageHeight": 1520,
    "ExifIFDPointer": 74,
    "Orientation": 0,
    "GPSInfoIFDPointer": 92,
    "LightSource": "Unknown",
    "GPSLatitude": [
        43,
        xx,
        17.861
    ],
    "GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
    "GPSLongitudeRef": "E",
    "GPSLongitude": [
        17,
        xx,
        7.29
    ],
    "thumbnail": {}
}
```

Comment: [Oracle Multimedia has been desupported in 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/release-changes.html#GUID-9320CABC-B720-4B9E-BC8C-E276332FAB5A), so you might want to look at alternatives anyway.

Comment: At the moment we are using Oracle 12c so I guess it's okay for now. However, it's a good advice.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal would be a Java class, e.g. [Apache Commons Imaging](https://github.com/apache/commons-imaging) or [org.w3c.tools.jpeg](https://jigsaw.w3.org/Doc/Programmer/api/org/w3c/tools/jpeg/package-summary.html) or [metadata-extractor](https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/)

First you need to load the Java classes into your database. Can be done with the `loadjava` tool:

```
loadjava -verbose -user username/password@DATABASE_NAME -r -o .\commons-imaging-1.0-alpha3.jar
```

Then you need to define the PL/SQL procedure/function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getMetadata(img IN BLOB) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Imaging.getMetadata(byte[] bytes) return java.lang.String';
/
```

In the final step you can use the PL/SQL as usual. Above function does not work, because of wrong return type but I hope you get an idea how it works in general.

See [Calling Java Methods in Oracle Database](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chthree.htm#JJDEV13165) and https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/oracle.sql.BLOB

Comment: Thanks for answer. I guess it would took me some time to analyze it since I am not so familiar with Java and should involve our DBA for loading classes in database.